# Striped background made with CSS is dependant on background-size in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, linear-gradients, background-size

When playing with striped gradients made with CSS, I found a strange behavior of IE, where the stripes became invisible after reducing the height value in the `background-size` property.

This behavior only in IE: Chrome and Firefox work as expected.

Here's the code :

#### The HTML

```html
<body>
  <div class="stripes all">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="stripes no_ie">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

#### The CSS

```css
.stripes {
    height: 500px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0 -10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.all {
    background-size: 100% 98px; /* Will show stripes in IE */
}

.no_ie {
    background-size: 100% 97px; /* Will not show anything in IE */
}
```

Here's the demo:
http://jsbin.com/jipehipobele/1/edit

Could someone explain to me why this happens and how to circumvent it, if possible?

Answer (score 1):

My workaround to this problem now is changing the tabstops of the gradient a little bit:

```css
 background-image: linear-gradient(red 1px, transparent 1.1px);
```

This works in IE and does not change the background-size. Thank you anyway, Taruckus for helping me find this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty weird issue. I found that it has to do with the browser scaling; if you zoom in at all using your browser / IE, the stripes will show. the zoom property is an old IE dog, so giving it a minimal value is hopefully an appropriate workaround.

```
.stripes {
height: 500px;
background-image: linear-gradient(red 1px, transparent 1px);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0 -10px;
background-color: white;
zoom:1.05;
}
```

more on zoom http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact pixel count of `background-size` does matter in this case. So zoom is not applicable.